# Change textfield on focus

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I implemented a undelined UITextField - therefore I added two functions, namely `underlined()` and `underlinedGrey`.

I works fine, but I want the textfield initially to be `textfield.underlinedGrey()`, as soon as the textfield is being focused: `textfield.underlined()`.

How can I implement this? I've already browsed the web and I found that I have to add a event listener, but so far nothing worked for me.

**Edit:**

```
extension UITextField {

    func clear () {
        self.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
            if $0 is CAGradientLayer {
                $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }

    func underlined(){
        clear()
        let color = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 95/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        let sndColor = UIColor(red: 124/255, green: 206/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [color, sndColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.8]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        let width = CGFloat(3.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func underlinedGrey(){
        clear()
        let color = UIColor(red: 112/255, green: 112/255, blue: 112/255, alpha: 0.4).cgColor

        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(3.0)
        border.borderColor = color
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` then implement

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  textField.underlined()
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  textField.underlinedGrey()
}
```

---

To clear

```
extension UITextField {
   func clear () {
     self.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
       if $0 is CAGradientLayer || $0.name == "MyLayer" {
          $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
       }
    }
 }
```

---

```
 let border = CALayer()
 border.name = "MyLayer"
 let width = CGFloat(3.0)
 border.borderColor = color
```

Comment: Thanks. Works so far, but I think since the function `underlined()` is being called in addition to the previously called `underlinedGrey()`, it mixes up the colors - can I somehow remove the previously called function?

Comment: from your older questions assuming it's a `CAGradientLayer ` so try calling `clear` in the beginning of the 2 underline methods

Comment: Yes it is. I've added it to my code but it's somehow still mixing up both gradients. To make everything clear - I'm currently calling `textfield.underlinedGrey` inside of `viewDidLoad` in addition to `textfield.delegate = self`.

Comment: inside `underlinedGrey` there is a `CALayer` not a `CAGradientLayer ` try edit

Comment: Changed it to a gradient and it works! Thanks! Since `underlineGrey()` is actually just a solid grey, I've added the same color again as `sndColor` for the gradient - I hope that won't cause any problems.